# Flutter SharedPreference Not updating values RealTime When Changed Unless App Closes and Restarts

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Please check the gif below.

[image]

I changed the language from English to French. It doesn't update realtime.

But when I close the app and open it, it shows French (Meaning it was saved in the preference)

I want it to change realtime as I update it.

**SharedPrefence.dart**

```
static String selectedLanguageKey = "language";
static SharedPreferences? _prefs;

static Future<SharedPreferences?> init() async {
_prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return _prefs;
}

static String? getSelectedLanguage() {
return _prefs?.getString(selectedLanguageKey);
}
```

**Home.dart**

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

String? _selectedLanguage;

void getSelectedLanguage() {
setState(()  {
_selectedLanguage = 
LocalPreference.getSelectedLanguage();
});
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
getSelectedLanguage();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.........

//there is a widget here that when tapped shows a modalbottomsheet where 
user selects a language

onTap: () {    
   showModalBottomSheet() 
}


//now here I display the current selected language, but it doesn't update 
 real time. Only when I close and open app
 Text(
  _selectedLanguage?? Strings.hindi, 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need update your `_selectedLanguage` every time came back from `ModalBottomSheet`. So change your `onTap` function to this:

```
onTap: () {    
   Future future = showModalBottomSheet() 
   
   future.then((_) {
      getSelectedLanguage();
    });
}
```

Comment: Did it fix your issue? @Ibramazin

Comment: Hey. I am still having issues even after using a combination of provider and your answer. It's still not updating real time

Comment: you don't need provider for only this case, remove that and try my answer.

Comment: Thanks..worked. I am curious, is it possible to do this too with state management like provider...why was it not working??

Comment: I don't know about provider but with bloc yes it can be done. With bloc you only need call the event that has the duty for getSelectedLanguage.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `getSelectedLanguage()` wont be called unless an Instance of `Home` is created which is the case when restarting the app.
What you can do is using a state management pattern for this, ex: provider and calling `notifyListeners()` when changing setting the language and you can access the language variable by calling the provider value, i.e. `Provider.of<LanguageProvider>(context, listen: false).language` or putting the language on the desired pages in a consumer.

You have other state managements patterns which may be also easier like GetX, Bloc...